# php remove character > when importing csv file

Tags: php

Please i need help, i am importing data from csv with php and i need to remove following character ">" from instock row in csv while importing. (Quantity array in php)

[CSV ROW instock - check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjkRW.png)

```
// MAIN CYCLE
$row_num = 0;
if (($handle = fopen($remote_csv_file, "r")) !== false) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ";")) !== false) {
    $row_num++;
    if ($row_num == 1) {
      // SKIP FIRST LINE (HEADER)
      continue;
    }
    //quantity = EAN --> STOCK
    if ($data[2] == '' || !is_numeric($data[3])) {
      // SKIP EMPTY VALUES
      continue;
    }
    //price = EAN --> PRICE
    if ($data[2] == '' || !is_numeric($data[1])) {
      // SKIP EMPTY VALUES
      continue;
    }
    //price bezna = EAN --> PRICE W
    if ($data[2] == '' || !is_numeric($data[0])) {
      // SKIP EMPTY VALUES
      continue;
    }
```

```
// INPUT SANITIZATION    
$ean13         = trim($data[2]); 
$quantity      = ($data[3] >= 0) ? $data[3] : 0;  //  need to remove ">" character from CSV row "instock" when importing data 
$price         = ($data[1] >= 0) ? $data[1] : 0;  // 
$price_wholesale   = ($data[0] >= 0) ? $data[0] : 0;  //
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What research have you done on "how to remove a character from a string"? Also note that you need to remove it _before you make a numeric comparison_.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) should do that for you using a space and the greater than sign as the characters to remove

```
trim($data[3], ' >');
```

Example

```
$data = ['a','b', 'c', ' > 12 '];

echo trim($data[3], ' >');
```

RESULT

```
12
```